# Doodle report: How to write "12:10 PM" literally in excel cell

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am using `doodle reports` in `ASP.NET MVC 5` in order to generate excel reports. I am having trouble with my time entries which are `string` in C#, but when I open the generated report in excel, the date is automatically prepended to time. Moreover, it automatically decides that it must shift them from 12 hours to 24 hours.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to prefix the `string` with a single quotation character `'`. That forces Excel to leave the data as text.

But doing that does mean that you won't be able to do any arithmetic with those fields.

Comment: Not an option. I am using same `IEnumerable` in my `view` and `report`. If I I do that, my web page will also have a single quote around time.